# ASP.NET Core send parameter validation using filters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, attributes, action-filter

I have controller method which have 2 input parameters : `DateTime dFrom, dtTo`.

So, now I check interval like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetValues([FromQuery] DateTime dtFrom, [FromQuery] DateTime dtTo)
{
    if (dtFrom > dtTo)
    {
        return BadRequest($"{nameof(dtFrom)} < {nameof(dtTo)}");
    }
}
```

But, I want to make validation like this:

```
[DateFilterAttribute(dtFrom,dtTo)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetValues([FromQuery] DateTime dtFrom, [FromQuery] DateTime dtTo)
{
    if (dtFrom > dtTo)
    {
        return BadRequest($"{nameof(dtFrom)} < {nameof(dtTo)}");
    }
}
```

Where `DateFilterAttribute`:

```
 public class DateFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
    private DateTime _fromDt;
    private DateTime _dtTo;
    public DateFilterAttribute(DateTime fromDt, DateTime dtTo)
    {
        _fromDt = fromDt;
        _dtTo = dtTo;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {            
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        var errorStr = $"{nameof(_fromDt)} < {nameof(_dtTo)}";
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Error", new string[] { errorStr });
    }
  }
```

But, I can not use input parameters at attribute.
So, can I do this? And is it right way?

Comment: Why just don't create an input contract with `dtFrom` and `dtTo` properties and implement `IValidatableObject` for date validation? Then 400 status code will be handled automatically

Answer (score 1):

For parameters passed in query string you can use the `HttpContext.Request.Query` directly and so you don't need to pass anything to your `DateFilterAttribute` constructor:

```
public class DateFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private DateTime _fromDt;
    private DateTime _dtTo;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        _fromDt = Convert.ToDateTime(context.HttpContext.Request.Query["dtFrom"]);
        _dtTo = Convert.ToDateTime(context.HttpContext.Request.Query["dtTo"]);

        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        var errorStr = $"{nameof(_fromDt)} < {nameof(_dtTo)}";
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Error", new string[] { errorStr });
    }
}
```

Now your `GetValues` shoud looks like this:

```
[DateFilterAttribute]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetValues([FromQuery] DateTime dtFrom,
                                          [FromQuery] DateTime dtTo)
{
    //The rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [ActionArguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutingcontext.actionarguments?view=aspnetcore-3.1) property, which has entries for each parameter used in our action.

```
public class DateRangeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var fromKey = "fromDate";
        var toKey = "toDate";

        if (!context.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(fromKey) ||
            !context.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(toKey))
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestResult();
            return;
        }

        if (!(context.ActionArguments[fromKey] is DateTime fromDate))
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestResult();
            return;
        }

        if (!(context.ActionArguments[toKey] is DateTime toDate))
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestResult();
            return;
        }

        if (fromDate > toDate)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new
            {
                Error = "Bad date range"
            });
            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

In our action

```
[DateRangeAttribute]
public IActionResult Index(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    return View();
}
```